# Beats Music API get user playlists

Tags: beatsmusic

Is there a way to get all playlists created by a user in the Beats Music API?

Is there a way to get all playlists followed by a user in the Beats Music API?

On looking at the docs, it seems the only way to get a playlist id is to create a new playlist - then you can work with that playlist, because you just created it. I'd like to be able to edit existing playlists created by a user, and browse songs on playlists that the user follows.

Answer (score 2):

[From the documentation](https://developer.beatsmusic.com/docs/read/playlists/User), it appears that you can get a list of user-created playlists.

> You can retrieve a user's playlist collection. If the playlists are not public, they must be owned by the user identified by the access token.

The response includes the playlist `id`s which is what you're looking for.

---

As for a user's subscriptions: [yes as well](https://developer.beatsmusic.com/docs/read/playlists/Subscriptions_User).

Comment: ah, yes - I was staring at the answer, but didn't see it clearly. Thanks - this worked for me!